# Auto Increment Id field API Laravel Resource

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am trying to add an auto incrementing key while sending response to frontend under Resources in Laravel.

Basically, I do not want to send DB Id field value to frontend.

Suppose i have below resource for one of my APIs:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id, <!-- This is DB Id, but it is not expected-->
        'name' => $this->name,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'code' => $this->code,
    ];
}
```

I need to add an auto increment key here, that shall always send incremented value. I want to do this because if data is deleted from DB for any of the row(say 3rd Row) then `Id` field is not suitable because then sequence will become 1,2,4

Comment: Why? What is the benefit of this? Your ID's will be incorrect in the frontend. If you want to achieve this, you can push to collection and use the collection index

Comment: Because i am not using IDs for any kind of operation. So that will not make any difference

Comment: You should still not alter it, you have an array on the frontend, so just use the index, this is not something the backend should do it will be inconsistent. But that is just me, I have been wrong before

Comment: I am using react-bootstrap-table for frontend and not able to figure out how to deal with index loop in that table

Comment: Perhaps post some code from your frontend...